# NON-English Character in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In external table snowflake is unable to read characters like "Ç" or non-English ones properly.

As per snowflake documentation, below is the format type options

```
formatTypeOptions ::=
-- If TYPE = CSV
     COMPRESSION = AUTO | GZIP | BZ2 | BROTLI | ZSTD | DEFLATE | RAW_DEFLATE | NONE
     RECORD_DELIMITER = '<character>' | NONE
     FIELD_DELIMITER = '<character>' | NONE
     FILE_EXTENSION = '<string>'
     SKIP_HEADER = <integer>
     SKIP_BLANK_LINES = TRUE | FALSE
     DATE_FORMAT = '<string>' | AUTO
     TIME_FORMAT = '<string>' | AUTO
     TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = '<string>' | AUTO
     BINARY_FORMAT = HEX | BASE64 | UTF8
     ESCAPE = '<character>' | NONE
     ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '<character>' | NONE
     TRIM_SPACE = TRUE | FALSE
     FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '<character>' | NONE
     NULL_IF = ( '<string>' [ , '<string>' ... ] )
     ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE | FALSE
     REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE | FALSE
     EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE | FALSE
     SKIP_BYTE_ORDER_MARK = TRUE | FALSE
     ENCODING = '<string>' | UTF8
-- If TYPE = JSON
     COMPRESSION = AUTO | GZIP | BZ2 | BROTLI | ZSTD | DEFLATE | RAW_DEFLATE | NONE
     DATE_FORMAT = '<string>' | AUTO
     TIME_FORMAT = '<string>' | AUTO
     TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = '<string>' | AUTO
     BINARY_FORMAT = HEX | BASE64 | UTF8
     TRIM_SPACE = TRUE | FALSE
     NULL_IF = ( '<string>' [ , '<string>' ... ] )
     FILE_EXTENSION = '<string>'
     ENABLE_OCTAL = TRUE | FALSE
     ALLOW_DUPLICATE = TRUE | FALSE
     STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE | FALSE
     STRIP_NULL_VALUES = TRUE | FALSE
     REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE | FALSE
     IGNORE_UTF8_ERRORS = TRUE | FALSE
     SKIP_BYTE_ORDER_MARK = TRUE | FALSE
-- If TYPE = AVRO
     COMPRESSION = AUTO | GZIP | BROTLI | ZSTD | DEFLATE | RAW_DEFLATE | NONE
     TRIM_SPACE = TRUE | FALSE
     NULL_IF = ( '<string>' [ , '<string>' ... ] )
-- If TYPE = ORC
     TRIM_SPACE = TRUE | FALSE
     NULL_IF = ( '<string>' [ , '<string>' ... ] )
-- If TYPE = PARQUET
     COMPRESSION = AUTO | LZO | SNAPPY | NONE
     SNAPPY_COMPRESSION = TRUE | FALSE
     BINARY_AS_TEXT = TRUE | FALSE
     TRIM_SPACE = TRUE | FALSE
     NULL_IF = ( '<string>' [ , '<string>' ... ] )
-- If TYPE = XML
     COMPRESSION = AUTO | GZIP | BZ2 | BROTLI | ZSTD | DEFLATE | RAW_DEFLATE | NONE
     IGNORE_UTF8_ERRORS = TRUE | FALSE
     PRESERVE_SPACE = TRUE | FALSE
     STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT = TRUE | FALSE
     DISABLE_SNOWFLAKE_DATA = TRUE | FALSE
     DISABLE_AUTO_CONVERT = TRUE | FALSE
     SKIP_BYTE_ORDER_MARK = TRUE | FALSE
```

Any settings to do in this file format options ?

Should the file format have something to handle this correctly ?

Comment: There should be no problem reading characters with diacritics in an external table. Can you update the question to show the error that you're getting?

Comment: You can only set the encoding for structured data (CSV, ENCODING = '<string>' | UTF8), for semi-structured (Avro/Json/Parquet) the encoding is always UTF8. What encoding are you using in your external files? "Ç" is part of UTF8 as you can see [here](https://www.charset.org/utf-8) but your issue is that you might use a different encoding rather than UTF8.